# Emacs VC ignore committed files (no svn:ignore)

Tags: svn, version-control, emacs

In netbeans I can ignore files existing in SVN repository (blue color on screen-shot), is there any way to do it in emacs Version Control system.

[image: ignoring files]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it in [psvn.el](http://www.xsteve.at/prg/vc_svn/) in your init.el add:

```
(add-to-list 'svn-status-elided-list "config/databases.yml")
```

where `"config/databases.yml"` is file path relative to root 
direcotry where `svn-status` was run.